# How to handle background and schedule task with asp web api

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have a saas web application using asp web api hosted in azure. I need to schedule some tasks to:

1. Generate monthly/yearly billing
2. Run recurring sql script
3. Send daily summary to users by email

Any recommendation or pointer on how i can do this? Should i create another app or can i host it inside my web api app?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a reliable tasks scheduling wherein you can apply time interval depend on your choice, I recommend [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/). Quartz allow to add/edit/delete/etc a scheduled task easily, manageable and no CPU overhead.

Answer (score 0):

This is what Azure Web Jobs are for - [running background tasks](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/).  It is a feature of the Azure Web App your Web API is running in.  You can set it up as a scheduled job using the Azure Scheduler.  How to do this is also in the link I provided.